# Message data type and accessing message fields

Tags: ros, hand-interaction, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use the /body_msgs/skeletons message (from the MIT hand_interaction demo).  I'm trying to write a subscriber callback function.  How can I tell the type of the message (for the callback prototype declaration)?

Also, this message has many fields (x,y,z coordinates of various joints).  How would I access any individual coordinate such as left_hip/y ?

Thanks,
Paul

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11811/message-data-type-and-accessing-message-fields/) by [Paul0nc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1067/paul0nc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 271 on 2011-11-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recommend following the relevant ROS tutorials on writing publishers and subscribers for your relevant language:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials

e.g. "Writing a Simple Publisher and Subscriber (C++)"

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-11-05**:
Multiple fields is no different from a single field: you just access the field by its name.  i.e. if you type "msg.data", you are accessing the 'data' field.

**Comment by [Paul0nc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1067/paul0nc/) on 2011-11-05**:
Thanks kwc.  I have worked through these tutorials.  I'm still not clear on how to access fields of a message or what is the type of a message composed of many variables.  The tutorials use standard types having only a single field.  Apologies if this is basic.